# Find the Schnyder 3-orientation of a plane triangulation graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

In 1990, Schnyder proved that the internal edges of a plane triangulation graph can be oriented such that each internal vertex has **exactly three outgoing edges** and **the vertices of the outer face have no outgoing edge**.

For a plane triangulation graph, I would like to find the Schnyder 3-orientation.

> Schnyder,W.: Embedding planar graphs on the grid. In: Johnson, D.S.
> (ed.) SODA 1990, pp. 138–148.SIAM (1990)

As can be seen from some literature,  software ([LEDA](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/%7Ealgorith/implement/LEDA/implement.shtml)) seems to be able to do this. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with this. I don't know if I can use mathematica to find the above orientation. Looking for such an orientation, the time complexity seems to be O(n) by above same paper.

For  a easy example, we obtain the Schnyder 3-orientation of the $K_4$. The unique internal vertex "4" has exactly three outgoing edges "41", 42" and "43".

[image]

[image]

For another example, Schnyder 3-orientation of the  plane triangulation graph in the following figure should be obtained by LEDA.

[image]

- Bre2000 Enno Brehm, 3-Orientations and Schnyder 3-Tree-Decompositions, 2000. [https://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~felsner/Diplomarbeiten/brehm.ps.gz](https://page.math.tu-berlin.de/%7Efelsner/Diplomarbeiten/brehm.ps.gz)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you give potential answerers *at least* something to work on, such as an example graph that you know can be oriented that way? What would you like the output to be? A graphical representation?

Comment: The output does not necessarily have to be a graphical representation , just a set of some directed edges by above 3-oriented .   Sorry, I have no  idea to start in this question.  All I can think of is the possibility of using brute force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding the orientation of the problem requires the algorithm of the following article.

- Bre2000 Enno Brehm, 3-Orientations and Schnyder 3-Tree-Decompositions, 2000. [https://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~felsner/Diplomarbeiten/brehm.ps.gz](https://page.math.tu-berlin.de/%7Efelsner/Diplomarbeiten/brehm.ps.gz)

It is equivalent to finding a Schnyder labeling. Sagemath currently has this algorithm built in. This is an alternative.

- https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/schnyder.html

```
sage: g = Graph([(0,-1),(0,2),(0,1),(0,-3),(-1,-3),(-1,2),
....: (-1,-2),(1,2),(1,-3),(2,-2),(1,-2),(-2,-3)], format='list_of_edges')
sage: g.set_embedding({-1:[-2,2,0,-3],-2:[-3,1,2,-1],
....: -3:[-1,0,1,-2],0:[-1,2,1,-3],1:[-2,-3,0,2],2:[-1,-2,1,0]})
sage: newg = minimal_schnyder_wood(g)
sage: newg.plot(color_by_label={'red':'red','blue':'blue',
....:  'green':'green',None:'black'})
```

[image]